# Is it a good idea to directly write function on pyuic5 generated py file?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I recently learn about Pyqt5 and have some confusion about it. I have finished designing my GUI using Designer and I convert it using the pyuic5 command to start writing function for it, lets say it generate a mainwindow.py. So my question is, is it a best practice to directly write a code on mainwindow.py or should I create a new python file that import it? I want to avoid problem of fixing this in the future. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally better to import it and extend it, since you can iterate design process and generate new file when design changes.